# Googlesheets api inserting a ' in cell value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

```
    let resources = {
      auth,
      spreadsheetId,
      resource: {
        valueInputOption: "RAW",
        data: [
          {
            range: "Shipping!C2:C4", // Update a column
            values: [
              [req.body.country],
              [req.body.packageWeight],
              [req.body.currency + "+6%"],
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values
      .batchUpdate(resources)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    if (req.body.shippingMethod === "DHL International Shipping") {
      const response = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values
        .get({
          auth,
          spreadsheetId,
          range: "Shipping!D8",
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      res.send(response.data);
    } else if (req.body.shippingMethod === "EMS International Shipping") {
      const response = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values
        .get({
          auth,
          spreadsheetId,
          range: "Shipping!C8",
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      res.send(response.data);
    }
  }
  return res;
};
```

The thing that is giving me goose bumps is that the packageWeight there is lets say a number: 1,2,3,4 etc these kinda numbers. But the output in Google Sheets = '1, '2, '3 etc for some reason. I have zero clue why the ' keeps getting added and blowing up my formulas on sheets. I have double and triple checked the values on the frontend side and there is no " ' " getting passed in. What the actual **** is causing this?? All the other cells are getting passed perfectly fine. All the console.logs are giving me the right values but the actual output has this stupid ' for some reason.

Comment: The `'` mean that the data is being read as a string. If this happens only for one row, maybe you should check from the Sheets UI either this rows is not formated as a number. Additionally, you can also explicitly convert `req.body.packageWeight` to a number before passing it to  `googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`

Comment: Thanks. Love you. Out of curiosity though whats the logic behind only ONE row inserting that single ' in front of the value?

Comment: It can be related to your data (`req`) and the way you retrieve it. You can use the method [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to retrieve the data type of your data.